# not able to show data from firebase to flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
showAllBatches () {

  return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('tcBatches')
          .where('academy_id', isEqualTo: acadamy_id)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text ("Loading...");

        return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {

              final int count = Category.categoryList.length > 10
                  ? 10 : Category.categoryList.length;

              final Animation<double> animation =
              Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                  CurvedAnimation(
                      parent: animationController!,
                      curve: Interval((1 / count) * index, 1.0,
                          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));
              animationController?.forward();

              return  BatchView (
                document: snapshot.data!.docs[index], dpi: dpi,
                //callback: onBatchPressed,
              );

            });
      });
}
```

i got this error while iam parssing the data

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: what do you expect to get from snapshot.data!.docs[index] ?

Comment: You are using `null` check operator (in this case exclamation mark (!)) on a null value. I think `snapshot.data!.docs[index]` causing the problem.

Comment: checking the data if it is null or not

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As, the error says, the returned data is null.

in the return statement, you have used **Null assertion operator** (`!.`), which means that the data CANNOT be null, but in fact your data (`snapshot.data`) is null.

learn more about Null Safety from the Dart Documentation:

- [null assertion operator](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety#the-null-assertion-operator) (`!.`)
- [null aware operator](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety#null-aware-operators) (`??` and `?.`)